# Added preferences dynamically that will last over sessions

Tags: android, session, state, preferences, persistent

I have preference defined in xml, and I do this addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences1); to create the pref activity. But in code (dynamically) at runtime somethimes(depends on busyness logic) I add more items like this

```
CheckBoxPreference c=new CheckBoxPreference(this);
            c.setKey("asdasd");
            c.setTitle("asd");
            getPreferenceScreen().addPreference(c);
```

This works great and everything is fine(the state is saved corectlly and it stays persistent) until I restart the phone. When I restart the phone this newly added item is lost. And only items from the xml file are shown in the prefereceActivity.

My question is what should I do to have this items even when the user restart the phone.

Comment: Did you save the preferences back to the xml or not?

Comment: yes, I want after reboot the phone that preferences I saved to be avaliable (not lost)

Comment: export the xml when u save to see if the data u want is there prior restoring?